JsonRequest no me da los valores de Android Studio pero si en la WEB
Tengo el siguiente código que consulta los datos de un WebService en PHP, pero el problema es que de un momento a otro el programa dejó de funcionar y me encontré con que la aplicación no realiza la conexión correspondiente y me arroja un error Volley (com.android.volley.authfailureerror). Revisé más y me dijeron que era recomendable pasar un encabezado "Mozilla/5.0" a la solicitud, pero no sé cómo ni dónde hacerlo:`private void buscarDatosLogin(String URL){
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    idvendedor=jsonObject.getString("id");
                    log=jsonObject.getString("nombre");
                    cont=jsonObject.getString("contrasenha");
                    permiso=jsonObject.getString("nombrecargo");

                    if(log.equals("vendedor")){
                        log="jurhe";
                        idvendedor="1";
                        permiso="administrador";
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            if (Logi.equals(log)&&Contra.equals(cont)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BIENVENIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                edtLog.setEnabled(true);
                edtCont.setEnabled(true);
                boton.setEnabled(true);
                ingresar();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            edtLog.setEnabled(true);
            edtCont.setEnabled(true);
            boton.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    );

    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);


}`

La versión de volley en Gradle es: 1.2.1
El logcat me da el siguiente error:

[217] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for

Me dieron el siguiente código para pasar el encabezado, pero no encuentro la manera de agregarlo al request, solo me pide importar Map pero sigue teniendo error en el retorno:
@Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        return headers;
    }

¿Alguien sabe cuál sería la forma correcta de agregarlo?

No creo que la solución sea agregar un encabezado relativo a Mozilla. ¿Si pruebas la URL en el navegador muestra algo? ¿El WebService requiere datos de autenticación?

cuando pruebo con la URL me muestra los valores correctamente, sigo con este inconveniente hace mucho tiempo

¿Qué pones en la URL y qué muestra en pantalla? ¿Has verificado que el valor de URL  en tu código Java es el mismo que pones en el navegador? Pulsa en [edit] para agregar esa información a la pregunta.
